# imshow() pixels are not accurately aligned with grid lines

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to draw line segments and polygons on top of an image displayed with imshow().  My problem is that the coordinates are precisely aligned with the pixels. I prefer maximum precision.

I created a minimum reproducible example with a checker pattern to make the problem easier to see.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n = 100
checkers = np.zeros((n, n))
checkers[1::2, ::2] = 0.8
checkers[::2, 1::2] = 0.8

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

ax.imshow(checkers * 255, interpolation='none', cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)

ax.grid(which='both', linewidth= 0.005, color='r')
ax.tick_params(which='both', width=0.1)
plt.setp(ax.spines.values(), linewidth=0.1)

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, n+1, 1), fontsize=1)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, n+1, 1), fontsize=1)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=1)

plt.savefig("grid_tests.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: grid lines (red) cross the center of the picxels(checker pattern)]

As you can see, the grid lines are loosing accuracy  on some regions of the image. I know that I could probably use pcolormesh instead, but this doesn't work with 3D (RGB) arrays.

Is there a way to make the grid and coordinates more accurate?

Comment: Where do you see that they are off?  If I zoom in, the very thin red lines always line up with the center of the thicker tick marks.  My guess is that, at the zoom level you have chosen there, the tick marks are an even number of pixels wide, in which case it is, of course, impossible to have a "center".

Comment: @TimRoberts I should have been more clear. The tick marks are not an issue. The issue is the the coordinates do not correspond the the centers of the squares (image pixels). This is highlighted by the grid lines, as the do not pass through the centers of the squares.

Comment: I see now.  If I use `plt.show()` to plot to the screen and change the `linewidth` to 0.5 (so they can be seen), they are perfectly centered.  Very interesting.

Answer (score -1):

By default the grid it starts at `-0.5`. You can fix that by setting the `extent` argument in `imshow` to start the grid from `0`:

````py
ax.imshow(checkers * 255, interpolation='none', cmap='gray', 
          vmin=0, vmax=255, extent=[0, n, 0, n])```
````

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but the red squares are still a tiny bit smaller than the black and white ones. And it's been a year I moved on.